# Beam java SDK，a java grammar confusion

Tags: java, apache-beam

In the Apache Beam Programming Guide https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-flatten-partition , I saw a code like this, I’m so confused with the Java grammar about the below, Please explain,Thanks.

```
PCollection<String> merged = collections.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections());
```

Why there is a dot`.` and a generic parameter`<String>` followed with a class`Flatten`? Who can tell me the java grammar of this?

Comment: Can you share a link to the programming guide where you got that code from?

Answer (score 0):

```
PCollection<String> merged
```

A declaration of an object named `merged` of generic class `PCollection<T>` with `String` type parameter.

```
collections.apply(...);
```

A call to the `apply(...)` method on an object called `collections`.

```
Flatten.<String>pCollections()
```

A call to the static generic method `<T> pCollections()` from the `Flatten` class with `String` type parameter.

I suggest you read about [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and [generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).